# Is there a way that django access the cookies stored by the browsers for authentication?

Tags: python, django, cookies

I have developed an internal website for my org ,which used some authentication at browser level (like login),they will authenticate on the start of the day and they want that authentication to even visit my website .I am accessing another service in the back-end which requires the same cookies which was stored by the browser when they authenticate .Is there a way i can get that cookies from the browser storage?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/django/django_sessions.htm

> For security reasons, Django has a session framework for cookies
> handling. Sessions are used to abstract the receiving and sending of
> cookies, data is saved on server side (like in database), and the
> client side cookie just has a session ID for identification. Sessions
> are also useful to avoid cases where the user browser is set to ‘not
> accept’ cookies.